# How can I update data from SQL in R?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a sample database in SQL and an RShiny app. I have a connection to the database and can retrieve the data.

I cannot get the Shiny app to update when new data is adding to the database. I can see how it works with CSV files but am not able to find anything similar for SQL.

This is my code:

```
library(RODBC)
library(shiny)

dbCon <- odbcConnect("SQL")
df <- sqlFetch(dbCon, "Test")
odbcClose(dbCon)

page_1 <- tabPanel(
  tableOutput('table')
) 

ui <- navbarPage( 
  page_1
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

output$table <- renderTable('table')

    myFile <- Q1
    
    data <- reactivePoll(1000, session,
                         # Returns the time the file was last modified (read that to be SAVED))
                         checkFunc = function() {
                           if (file.exists(myFile))
                             file.info(myFile)$mtime[1]
                           else
                             shinyalert(title = "file", text = "There is no such file")
                         },
                         # Get file content
                         valueFunc = function() {
                           dbCon <- odbcConnect("SQL")
                           df <- sqlFetch(dbCon, "Test")
                           odbcClose(dbCon)
                           output$table <- renderTable('table')
                         }
    )
  } 
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I believe I have two problems:

Q1. What should the path for 'myFile' be?

Q2. How should I write the code in the checkFunc function to see if the data has been updated?

Thanks

Comment: Can you "know" looking at the database that something is newer than what you already have? For instance, if you have a timestamp in your data, then include a filter such as `WHERE data_time > ..` where `..` is the `1e-6 + max(date_time)` of your local data; I use `1e-6` here because often there are floating-point issues with comparisons, so I force it a microsecond up. For the first query, just make sure your `max(date_time)` is set to something very early, such as `as.POSIXct("0001-01-01")`. After that, `rbind` new data with your local already-pulled data.

Comment: I can get a timestamp in SQL for the last update of the data (select MAX(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) from Test;) but I cannot currently call this from R. The db itself does not include a timestamp. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: What kind of DBMS do you have? If I understand correctly, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` has nothing to do with the data in the table, it's just "now". Does your data have any notion of when it was created and/or modified? Without those ... any other technique requires full admin mode on the database, and even then it's a lot of work and requires integration with big-picture triggers that are a bit heavy for this work. I'd think a better option is to alter the table with something like `CREATE TABLE quux (..., created DATETIMEOFFSET default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` or similar.

Comment: I have numerous tables where I do incremental downloads, only getting data when something is new or has changed. The "new" is easy enough, given the creation code I offer above; the "changed" is a bit more, and requires a trigger on the table that will update a column (perhaps named `"modified"`) whenever anything in the row is changed (but not on insertion). This is a common-enough thing among all databases. Once you have that, then `select ... where coalesce(modified, create) > ?` where `?` is the max of the relevant field(s) in my local data (default `"0001-01-01"` or such).